# URL set Connection Timeout is not working

Tags: java

I am using rss feeds to get latest news
 and i get a XML response back

The issue i am facng is that in case if it takes longer than 5 seconds i just want the program to be stopped 
this is my code (for testing purpose i have set time to 1 second)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     Connection dbConnection = null;
     PreparedStatement inserpstmt = null;
     try {
      final JSONArray latestnews = new JSONArray();
      builder = getDocumentBuilderInstance();
      final URL url = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8171434/rss.xml");
      url.openConnection().setConnectTimeout(1000);
      url.openConnection().setReadTimeout(1000);
      final Document doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
      final NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
      for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
       final Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
       final String title = getValue(item, "title");
       System.out.println(title);
      }
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      e.getMessage();
     } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.getMessage();
      e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
     }
    }
```

But could you please let me know why this isn't being stopped and waiting for more than 1 second

**Edited Code**

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8171434/rss.xml");
            URLConnection conn = new URL(sb.toString()).openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
            final   Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: You probably don't want to call `url.openConnection()` twice but reuse the connection.

Comment: Thnaks a lot , but i am directly using  url.openStream() , is it possible to use timeout on it ??

Comment: Thanks a lot i resolved the issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably approach this in the following fashion.

```
final URL url = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8171434/rss.xml");
URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
urlConn.setReadTimeout(1000);

final Document doc = builder.parse(urlConn.getInputStream());
```

Comment: thanks a lot , plz see the edited code in my question i resolved it this way .

Comment: Nice! Could you accept this as the answer to your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the above code each time when you call openConnection, you get a new Connection object. Also finally you are using openStream which is equivalent to openConnection().getInputStream(). So all the timeouts are on different connection object and finally there is no timeout set on the connection object from where inputstream is taken. That is why it was not working. Below code will work as timeouts are present on same object from where InputStream is retrieved.

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
connection.connect();
```